# php - Allowed Memory on while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have this while loop:

```
// Upgraded Checking
if($ir['upgraded'] < time()) $upgsql = " AND `aUpgraded`='0'"; 
else $upgsql = " AND ((`aUpgraded` = 1 AND `aUpgradedType` = '{$ir['upgname']}' AND `aUpgradedType` != '') OR (`aUpgraded` = 1 AND `aUpgradedType` = '') OR `aUpgraded` = 0)";

$ess=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE aClicksLeft3>0 AND aPaused='0' AND aApproved>0 ".$upgsql."");


while($extendedData == mysql_fetch_assoc($ess)){

$contents.="hey!!!";



};//End While
```

Whenever I run it, I get this error: 
**Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted**

I have no idea why this while loop is using this much memory to be executed. It's just a simply loop.

Anybody have any idea why it's acting like this? I have plenty of other while loop in my script, and I've never encountered this error before.

Comment: You're extending the value of $contents each iteration, so the memory usage is increasing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an infinite loop as you are comparing `$extendedData` to the result of the mysql fetch instead of assigning it. The loop keeps adding data to the `$contents` variable and at some point in the infinite loop it runs out of memory.

try

```
while( ($extendedData = mysql_fetch_assoc($ess)) ){
   $contents.="hey!!!";
};//End While
```

and think about using the mysqli functions instead of depreciated mysql functions.

Answer (score 1):

look out for https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
while($extendedData = mysql_fetch_assoc($ess))//should be single equal to sign here
{
$contents.="hey!!!";
}
```